# cannot get logback TRACE logs output for my java spring application

Tags: java, spring, logback, logback-classic

I am trying to use logback for `TRACE` logging for a Spring application. However, with the configuration I have, I only get up to `DEBUG` logs output to the console.

Any ideas if there is some configuration that will help me get `TRACE` as well?
I have read several tutorials and haven't found much. This is what I have so far for configuration:

using java 19

logback.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    </appender>
    
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

relevant pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `org.springframework.security` or your root have already some traces to emit? Try the inverse checking: set `<root level="WARN">` and `<logger name="org.springframework.security" level="ERROR">` and check that you are seeing less logs than now for both, and then exchange (`<root level="ERROR">`, `<logger name="org.springframework.security" level="WARN">`), or other levels, to see if the logs incoming are different. Then you will have checked that both declarations are working.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the logs look the same basically, still getting DEBUG logs even though my root and org.springframework.security are set lower than that. Also I know there should be at least one TRACE log because I made one myself to test and it doesnt show up when I hit the controller I put it in `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class); logger.trace("Info Message Logged ");` Same scenario but outputting .debug does print to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting spring security `trace` logging with your `logback.xml` file. So my take is that either spring security is not doing any trace logging in your scenario, or your `logback.xml` is not in effect. The latter can probably be eliminated if you get `debug` logging for spring security on your console...

Comment: I tested the your first idea by manually trace logging from a @Controller with this implementation: `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);
logger.trace("Info Message Logged ");` When I do .trace nothing appears in the console, but .info and .debug do appear. How do you get debug logging for spring security? I have tried @EnableWebSecurity(debug=true) in the annotation for my security config class

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, just to confirm I get spring security DEBUG logs, the answer is yes for example: `54:13.321 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /WEB-INF/view/ticket-list.jsp`

Comment: with that logger I have the exact same behavior.

Comment: If you want to try logging yourself, better make sure you are logging using the right logger...  Use `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.springframework.security")` instead to make sure... If you get the message you should get the trace logs from the lib as well, I looked at the source and it only tests if the logger is enabled for trace...

Comment: You can also call `logger.isTraceEnabled()` to test the log level...

Comment: Perhaps also try modifying the log pattern in the `logback.xml` file and verify that it is reflected in the logs, in order to verify that it is using your config...

Comment: I get the log message when logging to debug or error but not when trace. Nothing I change in logback.xml is effecting any other part of the application. it seems like it is ignored for some reason.

Comment: ok... so it looks like I have two different issues. 1: TRACE and DEBUG are disabled per the output of those logger methods. 2: the application isnt picking up the logback.xml, because the pattern is the same even after changing it in the file. I have trace=true and debug=true in application.properties..

Comment: keep in mind, I didnt begin this as a boot project, it is just normal spring. I added the boot configuration per the suggestion of someone else in this question.

Comment: ok.... I just moved application.properties and logback.xml to a different directory on the build path and now both are working. I have no idea why that would matter

Comment: They should both go into the root of the resources folder…

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I show you a logback test config I use for logging?
It is working for me. I hope it can give you ideas to find where your issue is coming from, by comparing with yours?

logback-test.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="/tmp/ecoEmploi-test-sparkDatasetEntreprise.log"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <logger name="fr" level="DEBUG" />

    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler" level="WARN" />

    <logger name="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat" level="WARN" />

    <logger name="org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileSourceStrategy" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec" level="WARN" />

    <logger name="org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.CodecConfig" level="WARN" />

    <logger name="org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl" level="WARN" />

    <logger name="org.apache.spark.executor.Executor" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator" level="WARN" />

    <logger name="org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore" level="WARN" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried adding in your `<include>`s, renaming the file, and importing the boot dependencies into POM. Now it only logs up to INFO. Seems like Spring Boot/Spring have their own defaults for logging and they're ignoring logback-test.xml. Tried to delete the file, rebuild the project, re-add and rebuild and still nothing different.

Comment: logback.xml is on the classpath, it's in the same directory as web.xml which is configuring something successfully.